# Error message: Error in fn(x, ...) : Downdated VtV is not positive definite

Tags: r, lme4

I'm trying to use the lmer function to create a minimum adequate model. My model is Mated ~ Size * Attempts * Status + (random factor).

```
as.logical(Mated)
as.numeric(Size)
as.factor(Attempts)
as.factor(Status)
```

(These have all worked on previous models)

So after all that I try running my model:

```
Model1<-lmer(Mated ~ Size*Status*Attempts + (1|FemaleID),data=mydata)
```

And it can be submitted without fault.It's only when I try to apply this update that it goes wrong:

```
Model2<-update(Model1, REML=FALSE)
```

Here is the error message supplied:

> Error in fn(x, ...) : Downdated VtV is not positive definite

If I make a third model without the interaction and do an ANOVA between that and model one, then it says the two are significantly different.

```
Model3<-update(Model1,~.-Size:Status:Attempts
anova(Model1,Model3)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the three way interaction really significant or have I made some mistake?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If `Mated` is binary, then you should probably be using `glmer` with a logit or probit link function instead, something like:

```
model <- glmer(Mated ~ Size * Status * Attempts + (1|FemaleID), 
data = mydata, family = binomial)
```

It would help if you could let us know what your data looks like (`head(mydata)` might be fine, or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for how to make a reproducible example).

Also, I would avoid making `Mated` logical (see [this question and answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72882/puzzling-behavior-of-glmer) for how it can make your life more difficult). Instead, `as.factor(Mated)` will explicitly make your response variable discrete.

After that, you can compare your full and reduced models with `anova()`.