# Error message with confidence interval using lmer

Tags: r

I am trying to estimate the following model. My objective is to calculate confidence interval of the random parameters.

```
variation.model1 =lmer(sales ~ 1+age+value_added+net_worth+(1+net_worth|industry:id)+
                           (1+net_worth|industry), 
                       data=data_file, 
                       control = lmerControl(calc.derivs = FALSE), 
                       REML=T, na.action=na.omit)
```

I got the following errors.

```
confint(variation.model1, which="theta_")
```

> Error in  profile.merMod(object, which = parm, signames = oldNames, ...) formal argument "which" matched by multiple actual arguments

```
confint(variation.model1)
```

> Error in fn(x, ...) : Downdated VtV is not positive definite In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

What should I do with this type of problem?

My data structure:
  industry id year  Sales  age value_added net_worth
1        1  1    0  1.017 3.93        14.0      12.9
2        1  2    0 -0.780 3.90        13.2      13.1
3        1  2    3 -0.402 3.90        13.2      11.6
4        1  3    0  0.722 3.69        14.4      14.5
5        1  3    2  1.437 3.69        14.4      13.2
6        1  3    4  1.545 3.69        14.4      13.9

Sorry for unreadable data.

In addition, I also tried using lme. I got the following error message for

diag(variation.model1$apVar)

Error in diag(variation.model2$apVar) :
invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)

In addition: Warning message:
In diag(variation.model2$apVar) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Check out [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

1) `confint` does not have an argument `which` - if you only want confidence intervals of certain parameters use `parm`.

```
confint(variation.model1, parm="theta_")
```

2) Your second problem I could not reproduce with my data and since I do not know what your variables are, a guess is going to be a blow in the wind. But perhaps your question is already answered here:
[Error message: Error in fn(x, ...) : Downdated VtV is not positive definite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990948/error-message-error-in-fnx-downdated-vtv-is-not-positive-definite)

Comment: Thanks for your  help for the first problem. I could not figure out  the second problem. I have read that link before. I add the data structure. In addition, I add more information about this problem.